# Cannot Run HighChart GWT Demo Example - Area Range

Tags: gwt, highcharts, gwt-highcharts

I am trying to get an area chart in my application however, I cannot get even the most basic one displayed (I literally checked to see if their implementation would work but it doesnt and throws this error)

Example I tried to run http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/showcase/#area-range

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError)
>   @org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.BaseChart::nativeRenderChart(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;ZZLcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)([string:
>   'Chart', JavaScript object(10), bool: false, bool: false, JavaScript
>   object(36), JavaScript object(37), JavaScript object(38), JavaScript
>   object(26), JavaScript object(32), JavaScript object(25), JavaScript
>   object(30), JavaScript object(31), JavaScript object(34), JavaScript
>   object(35)]): $wnd.Highcharts is undefined

Is it possible im using the incorrect JQuery? Any and all help is greatly appreciated since this feature is important to our application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error was that while I was including highcharts.js, i was not including highcharts-more.js. Including this solved my problem!!